# Profiler for Visual Studio 2008, C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, profiler

Are there any good, free (or at least reasonably cheap) 
profilers for at least native C++ that can integrate with 
Visual Studio 2008 Professional?

I looked at [DevPartner](http://www.compuware.com/products/devpartner/profiler/default.asp?cid=701000000004ej0AAA&focus=&productfocus=&source=Web+-+Evaluation+Request&offering=DevPartner&productfamily=DevPartner&desc=The+DevPartner+Community+Profiler+Edition+is+a+product+download+that+offers+customers+and+prospects+a+high-level+view+of+the+performance+profiling+capabilities+of+DevPartner+Studio+Professional+Edition.&trk=200601-74) community edition but they 
seem to only support Visual Studio 2003 and Visual Studio 2005.

Failing that are there any good free/cheap profilers in 
general that I can get working with VS with relativly little 
friction?

Answer (score 8):

At my workplace we use [AQTime](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/aqtime/). It's not free ($600 or 30-day trial) but it really works wonders. I like it because it can handle both native (we do C++) and managed code. It works in stand-alone mode, integrates with Visual Studio, and also works with Borland's IDE (for those C++ Builder and Delphi fans out there).

But I will be watching this question to see if there are any free tools I can use at home =)

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft actually provides a stand-alone verson of the profiler, which you can use from the command-line. 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=fd02c7d6-5306-41f2-a1be-b7dcb74c9c0b&displaylang=en

Comment: It seems that to view its output you need to have VS2008TS. OP asked about Professional version.

Comment: Another possibility would be in this article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/profileWithVsPerfCmd.aspx

Comment: Microsoft Performance Drivers cannot be installed on Win8 and upper

Answer (score 1):

Another vote for AQTime. We've been really happy with it. But of course it's not free as you asked...

I tried CodeAnalyst once but as far as I could see it was doing polling rather than instrumentation, and hence gave fairly crude results. Haven't found any free profilers for Windows that I liked better than that.

Answer (score 1):

Free profiler for VS 2008:
http://unick-soft.ru/Articles.cgi?id=8
It is russian article, but you can use translate google com.

Answer (score 1):

[This technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024) is free, and works well in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

http://supercomputingblog.com/windows/how-to-profile-c-code-in-visual-studio-for-free/ if you want something very simple

Answer (score 0):

Intel's VTune or AMD's CodeAnalyst are both free, I believe.

Comment: Intel's VTune is not free (although there is an evaluation).