# Is there something like ANTS Performance Profiler but for C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, profiler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Profiler for Visual Studio 2008, C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292457/profiler-for-visual-studio-2008-c)

Hi
Are there any profilers for C++ ?? 
I need something which would investigate weak points of my application - by weak I mean not optimalized. Usualy I do this using ANTS Performance Profiler but this time my application is written in c++ and I don't know if there are any tools for this task.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67554/whats-the-best-free-c-profiler-for-windows-if-there-are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something simple but effective, [there's this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624667/whats-a-very-easy-c-profiler-vc/2624725#2624725).

Comment: You should include a summary of the answer in addition to the link.   What happens if the link breaks?

Answer (score 1):

Does this [Help](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/Profilers/CppProfiler.html)?

Comment: You should include a summary of the answer in addition to the link.   What happens if the link breaks?