# Which part of my code is running?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, optimization

I have a 5k lines software that is running, and it is running at 50% CPU usage. It's quite high, and I used some 3rd party assemblies. So can I from Visual Studio, determine which part of my code is running, without using breakpoint? Using breakpoint won't detect CPU usage, because the program is not running when it stop at that particular point.

I am using visual studio 2010, c#.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have Analyze\Launch Performance Wizard on your VS.Net menu?  If so - try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need *Visual Studio® Team System Development Edition* or *Visual Studio Team Suite*. If you have one, run [Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx) using the Performance Wizard. ([list of other profliers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292457/profiler-for-visual-studio-2008-c)).

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010 Premium, and I have the profiler. That's what I want, thanks.